# How insert the sum from other tables in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

TABLE ORDINIUA

```
| ordiniua(pk) | fornitore | elemento | stimaarrivo | arrivato |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|   8ec230     |   ABB     |    17    |  10/10/2017 |    0     |
|   8ec520     |   STE     |    147   |             |    1     |
|   8ec234     |   FIS     |    17    |  25/06/2017 |    1     |
```

TABLE QUADRI

```
| elemento(pk) | numeroco  |descrizione| colonne | Ordini_Arrivati|
------------------------------------------------------------------
|   22         | 251.06/17 |           |    6    |    the sum     |
|   17         | 168.05/17 |           |    0    |    the sum (1) |
```

Whre I wrote "the sum" i'd like to have the sum of table Ordiniua field "arrivato" where "elemento" is the same. e.g.: arrivato on 8ec520 is 0, arrivato on 8ec234 is 1, the sum is 1.

Is it possible to aumatically generate this value (like excel "sum if") ?
If yes how?

Comment: Add your tables and describe the problem a bit better

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Also see SUM and GROUP BY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you want you should use `MySQL Triggers`. When you `INSERT` a new row:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER insertDatabase
BEFORE INSERT ON ordiniua
FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
       UPDATE quadri s
           SET s.Ordini_Arrivati = s.Ordini_Arrivati + new.arrivato
       WHERE s.elemento = new.elemento;
END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

And when you `UPDATE` an existing row. Be careful about the `UPDATE` because you will have to know the difference between the previous value and the current value inside the arrivato column.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER updateDatabase
BEFORE UPDATE ON ordiniua
FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
       UPDATE quadri s
           SET s.Ordini_Arrivati = s.Ordini_Arrivati + new.arrivato
       WHERE s.elemento = new.elemento;
END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

You could want to have a Trigger to `DELETE`, but as you can see you just have to follow the logic. Wish it could help you